# CallBack functions, which is the proper way

Tags: asp.net, callback

So, I am fairly knowledgable in Asp.net 2.0 and Windows stuff mostly.  A friend gave me his 3.5 book  (Asp.net 3.5 SP1 in C# and VB Wrox).  I know it is not the latest but it was free.

So in Chapter 2 they talk about doing Callback and not full post-backs.  I use to accomplish this by an Ajax update panel.

They describe creating two JavaScript functions, the call wrapper and the result function and then the server side dynamically creates the caller using Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock.  The class implements ICallBackEventHandler that calls RaiseCallBackEvent

My questions are:

- what is the best method nowadays: the way described above, Ajax update panels, jQuery.Post, jQuery.ajax?
- Under which Frameworks will each option work?
- What are the situations where you might use one over the other?  Like size or complexity of the parameters/return results?

Thank you

Comment: Also free, and the latest: [asp.net tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Comment: I am working through that also.  Thanks

Comment: I can't edit my own comment, however will the MVC track cover call backs I am only on Section 5, I didn't really see it listed in Section 6

Answer (score 2):

I would always use `jQuery.post` or `jQuery.ajax` over the use of UpdatePanel in ASP.NET WebForms.

It wins over performance as you are only requesting what you need, and there is no viewstate overhead.